# User doesn't accept Cookies - login PHP

Tags: php, cookies

In my login code on my website, if the password & username are correct, I set a cookie to keep the user logged in.
I just heard from a user that he doesn't accept cookies automatically through his browser, and that that prevents him from logging in. That rhe cookie is not set.

Is there an easy way to counter that?
Tell me if you need the code I use.

Comment: While I appreciate that some users clear cookies regularly/disable them, I don't think it's unreasonable to say that for the use of some features on your site (eg those requiring a login) cookies are required. There are potential workarounds with flash hacks or html5 local storage but this is what cookies were designed for and I'd suspect that your user doesn't quite understand that (perhaps only being aware of tracking cookies?)

Comment: @Basic Or just pass the session id in the URL (wich is also a terrible solution). To OP: The user is not worth the time you have to spend in coming up with some ugly work around. If he doesn't accept the cookie that's his problem.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 I was just typing that up in an answer :)

Comment: Thanks alot guys. This is why I love this website ;-) I'll think about putting a message if the cookies are disabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get this to work but often a real pain if you're using complex javascript/ajax.

In short, instead of storing the session id in a cookie, you embed it at the end of every link.

so

```
http://example.com/somepage.php
```

becomes

```
http://example.com/somepage.php?SessionId=ABC123
```

Unfortunately, while PHP can do this for you in some cases, it doesn't help with links you build yourself in javascript - and it only takes clicking a single link without the id to effectively log the user out

See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) for more information

As mentioned by Quentin in the comments, if you're not using a cookie to identify the browser which created the session, it's possible that sharing a link would share the session. This could be mitigated but not prevented by checking IP address/user agent but this would likely fail in large corporate environments with NAT and standard browsers

Comment: Storing the session id in the URL makes it very easy to leak it by accident, this technique introduces a serious security risk.

Comment: Alice goes to a website that is selling Stuff. She gets a session id to associate her with her shopping basket. She likes a Thing. She copy/pastes the URL from her address bar into Twitter to share the Thing with other people. Bob likes the Thing too and adds it to Alice's shopping basket, then sees everything else in her shopping basket.

Comment: Excellent, and spot on. Thanks for the answer Basic, but I think I'll try  and simply put a message if the user desactivates his cookies. Thanks again.